# Where do I have to insert the configuration code for jQuery Countdown Plugin by Keith Wood localisation in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-countdown

I've been having some difficulties finding the file and exact place where I need to add the localization configuration for Keith Wood's countdown timer.

> 1. I already loaded the language package into the js folder.
> 2. Added this script into header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown-es.js"></script>
```

But I don't know where to add these:

> Restores the original language settings:

```
$.countdown.setDefaults($.countdown.regionalOptions['']);
```

> And the configuration per countdown:

```
$('#l10n').countdown($.countdown.regionalOptions['es']); 
$('#l10n').countdown($.extend({other options...}, $.countdown.regionalOptions['es']));
```

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is include the main countdown.js file and then include the localisation.js file after.

If you are trying to translate to Spanish, then add this code only to the localisation.js file:

```
(function($) {
    $.countdown.regionalOptions['es'] = {
        labels: ['Años', 'Meses', 'Semanas', 'Días', 'Horas', 'Minutos', 'Segundos'],
        labels1: ['Año', 'Mes', 'Semana', 'Día', 'Hora', 'Minuto', 'Segundo'],
        compactLabels: ['a', 'm', 's', 'g'],
        whichLabels: null,
        digits: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
        timeSeparator: ':', isRTL: false};
    $.countdown.setDefaults($.countdown.regionalOptions['es']);
})(jQuery);
```